# Move line up/down shortcut in chrome devtools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is there "move line" up/down keyboard shortcut in google chrome devtools` source code?

(analogical to PHP storm's `[alt]`+`[shift]`+`[up]` or `[alt]`+`[shift]`+`[down]`)

Can't find anything on that, would be really handy.

Comment: What type of line do you want to move up and down? A line in the Elements panel (i.e. a DOM node)? A line in the Sources panel (i.e. a line of source code)? I haven't heard of a shortcut in either case, but it might make for a good feature request.

Comment: Thanks @KayceBasques, i was thinking about source-code but why wouldn't it move DOM element as well? Can i contribute by opening feature request?

Comment: @KayceBasques actually move DOM element is doable by pressing [ctrl]+[shift]+arrow